# Deploying WAR file in Tomcat (Configuring to deploy it in a domain)

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, path, war

First of all thank you to read me and try to help me!

I'm working for the first time with Tomcat 9. I have a WAR file of my project and I want to deploy it in my domain. But I'm having some problems. I have been looking for different tutorials and reading here differents solutions but I cant get one that works for me.

I can deploy my WAR file in http://localhost:8080/myProjectMed/ but I would like to **deploy it in my domain**: www.getInfo.ue.com/spyInv ... How can I do this with Tomcat 9?

Thank you guys :)

Comment: are you using eclipse ??

Comment: @AnishB. yes, to build the WAR file.

Comment: url : www.getInfo.ue.com/spyInv - this you want

Comment: @AnishB. that is a example URL, my URL is similar. I just want to deploy my WAR file in a my domain using Tomcat.